# MassTransit: Cannot access Azure Service Bus using managed Identity

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-managed-identity

I have the following code in the Azure function start up

```
 builder.Services.AddScoped<ExampleConsumer>()
                .AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<ConsumerNamespace>();
                }, "AzureWebJobsServiceBus");
```

Configuration:

```
AzureWebJobsServiceBus__fullyQualifiedNamespace:  <service_bus_name>.servicebus.windows.net
```

Function Signature:

```
public Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(<topic_name>, <subscription_name>, Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")] string message, FunctionContext context)
```

Its throwing exception

```
System.ArgumentNullException: A connection string must be used for Azure Functions. (Parameter 'AzureWebJobsServiceBus')
```

What should be the proper way to configure MassTransit for Azure function to connect Azure Service Bus using managed identity?

I explored the mass transit source code and found that it is expecting connection string containing SharedAccessKeyName and SharedAccessKey otherwise throw exception. Any alternative way to configure ?

- MassTransit.WebJobs.ServiceBus version 8.0.7
- Azure Function v4 and
  .NET6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following code in the Azure function start up

```
 builder.Services.AddScoped<ExampleConsumer>()
                .AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<ConsumerNamespace>();
                }, "AzureWebJobsServiceBus:MassTransit");
```

Configuration:

```
AzureWebJobsServiceBus:fullyQualifiedNamespace:  <service_bus_name>.servicebus.windows.net
```

For MassTransit:

```
AzureWebJobsServiceBus:MassTransit:Endpoint=sb://<service_bus_name>.servicebus.windows.net
```

Function Signature:

```
public Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(<topic_name>, <subscription_name>, Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")] string message, FunctionContext context)
```

I have to provide two connection strings for Azure Function trigger and MassTransit. The difference between these two for mass transit it starts with `Endpoint=sb://`